# Turn off simulate user location by Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using iPhone 4 to test my iOS app.

In my project I have .gpx files that allow me to simulate some specific location when iPhone is plugged in to my Mac. Unfortunately when I unplug my iPhone I still see that location, not the current user location.

Is it possible to set user location back? How can I achieve that?

I tried disable and re-enable user location, delete and install application, but it doesn't work. Looks like it is not possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Delete the app from the device.
2. Under "Edit Scheme" uncheck the Core Location "Allow Location Simulation" setting.
3. IMPORTANT STEP! Turn the device off and then back on. (Clears out the GPX file, I believe).
4. Then re-load the app to the device.

Comment: Should be sufficient to just restart the device. Works for me. I also was able to fix it by running the app again and selecting "Don't simulate location" at the top of the "Simulate Location" submenu in "Debug" in Xcode and then stopping the app from Xcode, but it seems this may no longer work in Xcode 9.4 / iOS 11.4.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler working solution is:

In XCode goto Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

Options -> Default Location: None

Rebuild application